# MySQL query is fast but when I make it subquery it becomes very slow

Tags: mysql

When I query this:

```
select
   *
from
   userlogs_temp
where
   (
       last_analyze_time is NULL
           OR
       last_analyze_time < acctupdatetime
   )
   and
       came_from_other_servers = 0 and
       radacctid % 10 = 4
```

This is the profile of that query (1583 total row, **0.0009 seconds**)

[image: first query profile]

But when I run this query:

```
select
   *
from
 (
    the above query
 ) sq
```

This is the profile of that query (1583 total row, **0.8052 seconds**)

[image: second query profile]

What can be the problem? I think the problem is creating temp tables, but disk i/o performance is normal. How can I found the problem? When I try same data and same queries on my laptop, everything works normal, second query takes nearly same time as first one.

This is my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock


#innodb
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=256M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 6
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2


slow-query-log=1
long-query-time=1
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
max_connections=250
key_buffer_size=8192M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
table_open_cache=100000
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=4096K
read_rnd_buffer_size=2048K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=2048M
query_cache_limit=5M
query_cache_size=4096M
query_cache_type=0
event_scheduler=ON
thread_cache_size=50
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
open-files-limit=65535
table-definition-cache=4096
table-open-cache=10240

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 






[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
connect_timeout=15
interactive_timeout=60
```

Comment: it just auto-recommended, I removed it now, thank you.

Comment: During the second way of querying, there's a big bottleneck of "Sending Data", which is in .802 `milliseconds` while other steps are in `microseconds`. Please check with the profiler, what exactly `Sending data` means, which may help you understand the reason.

Comment: Yes, I think this is about PMA itself, when I query first one, it just limit first 25 rows and this is why it took 0.0009 seconds. When I run the same query on mysql interface on SSH, it just takes ~0.6 seconds. So, when I make it a subquery, PMA does not limit the output I think. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your complete my.cnf.  Observations you may wish to consider.

my.cnf things to do:
in [mysqld] section, REMOVE to allow system DEFAULTS to work for you:
key_buffer_size
per connection RAM requested is unusually extreme for the next 2
read_buffer_size
read_rnd_buffer_size

See MySQLCalculator.com for more likely realistic default values.

For additional specific in depth configuration suggestions, please post complete text results of:
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

Comment: One additional change in my.cnf you may wish to consider.
You have query_cache_type =0   which is off, to economize on RAM, change
query_cache_size=1M # from 4096M because only a few K will be used.